# Google Sheets Preset Conditional Formatting Rules?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I currently have a Google sheet conditionally formatted the way I need it. The problem is when I share the sheet, people often copy and paste cells messing up the conditional formatting rules. Is it possible to somehow store my preferred conditional format rules in a macro, then when someone edits the sheet, it will auto reset any changes to the preferred rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try duplicating the sheet where you have the pristine conditional formatting rules in place. To restore the formatting:

1. Go to the pristine sheet.
2. Press **Control+A** once or twice to select all cells.
3. Press **Control+C**.
4. Go to the messy sheet.
5. Select cell `A1`.
6. Choose **Edit > Paste special > Paste conditional formatting only**.

The process can be automated with a script like this:

```
function resetMessyConditionalFormatting() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const pristineRange = ss.getSheetByName('Pristine').getDataRange();
  const messyRange = ss.getSheetByName('Messy').getRange('A1');
  pristineRange.copyTo(messyRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING, false);
}
```

Comment: I came up with a similar solution once I posted, but this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I created a template with only the formatting.

```
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Formatting");
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ASR Tracker");
  ss2.clearConditionalFormatRules()
  ss1.getRange("A2:AI985").copyTo(ss2.getRange("A2:AI985"), {formatOnly:true});
```